# loading string of json arrays in python

Tags: python, json

I have a file like this and each line contains something like this string:

`[{u'text': u'this', u'freq': 1}, {u'text': u'is', u'freq': 1}, {u'text': u'a', u'freq': 1}, {u'text': u'test', u'freq': 1}]`

I tried to load each line into json object but I get this error:

```
for lineid, line in enumerate(open("myfile.txt")):
    jsonline=json.loads(line)
```

I get the following error:

```
raise ValueError(errmsg("Expecting property name", s, end))
ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 2 (char 2)
```

I want to retrieve all 'text' from the file and have it in each line. So each line will not be json but will be the sequence of text space separated. Example:

`this is a test`

Comment: Is each line an item in a larger list?

Comment: each line is a line in a large file.

Comment: @Nick I noticed that you have never accepted any answer for your questions. I you don't want to, that is completely fine and you can ignore this comment. Just reminding you of the feature in case you forgot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not JSON, that's a Python literal.

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval("[{u'text': u'this', u'freq': 1}, {u'text': u'is', u'freq': 1}, {u'text': u'a', u'freq': 1}, {u'text': u'test', u'freq': 1}]")
[{u'text': u'this', u'freq': 1}, {u'text': u'is', u'freq': 1}, {u'text': u'a', u'freq': 1}, {u'text': u'test', u'freq': 1}]
```

Comment: Thanks. Does it change it to the json object? How can I then retrieve the "text" fields?

Comment: It becomes a Python object. You treat it as you would the corresponding Python object.

Comment: Thanks. What do you think is the best way of extracting the "text" items? regular expression or json or ...?

Comment: How about accessing them the same way you would any other Python dict?